# How to inspect shared worker in OpenFin?

Tags: javascript, debugging, inspect, shared-worker, openfin

I'm looking for an option to inspect [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) thread to debug and check console logs, when application running on OpenFin.

I have been debugging my javascript react based application in chrome developer tool and shared workers inspect accessible at chrome://inspect/#workers. But when running on OpenFin, I could not find any option to inspect shared worker.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to devtools_port (by default it is http://localhost:9090). You should see your shared workers on the list of running openfin apps. Select one of the workers to access its console logs.